# How to zoom in Android Layout Editor?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

This is how Layout Editor looks like when I click on **Preview all Screen sizes**

[image: XML Layout Editor]

Clicking on + and - does nothing. Without zooming I can't see Preview on all Screen sizes clearly. How can I zoom in and out to see everything clearly?

Is this a issue with Android Studio or I am doing it wrong way?

Comment: must read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android

Comment: @sushildlh i could not find anything related to my question there?

Comment: i think zoom is working only with single device .

Comment: Yeah , i want to know if zoom is possible with Preview all Screen sizes

Comment: Are you on ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, but what solved for me was changing the theme of Android Studio. When I couldn't zoom in or out in the XML Editor I just changed from Darcula theme to IntelliJ theme and it worked just fine.

I hope it works for you too or someone have the same issue!

Comment: I had to change the API level or the device from inside the "Design" view of the layout xml.

Comment: Thank you for the clue. In my case, I must change the theme from Intellij to Darcula. and after close & open Android Studio, zoom can work normally.

Comment: I too had to switch from Intellij theme to Darcula theme. After pressing apply I had to close and then reopen Android Studio. Once I did that I could zoom in and out. If I switched back to the IntelliJ theme then the buttons stopped working again.

Answer (score 1):

Change it from Design + Blueprint to Design only. Works for me

Answer (score 1):

I've just had to resolve the same problem. Restart your AS - Select Design Surface - Force Layout Refresh. Refresh it several times. Maybe its irrelevant but I also made the program window smaller and than bigger again. It helped.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem, and none of the suggestions above worked for me.

Finally, I tried changing the device type (e.g. switching from Pixel to Nexus 6P) and that worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Almost always when I create a new empty project in Android Studio 3.2.1, I have this problem, after just changed from IntelliJ   theme to Dracula   theme and it worked just fine.
After I changed the theme from Dracula to Intellij, zoom also can work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your Android Studio perhaps. Sometimes it just stop working.

Answer (score 0):

I switched into Blueprint mode and it zoomed and it now works when I go back to the Design + Blueprint view

Answer (score 0):

in my android studio (v 3.3) zoom size was locked in 7% and didnt change at all. after I install all of system image required in api target in sdk platform, when i resize by mouse(like picture) suddenly change that 7% and after that it works.Actually I dont know what action solve the problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6hnQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The most probably solution would be resize the android studio window which can be done my dragging your mouse after clicking on the edge of the studio's window, which will automatically result in resized layout .

Now since the layout is resized implicitly its most likely to work explicitly as well.

Worked for Me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Android studio version 3.4.1:
Go File -> Invalidate caches/Restart click it, has solve this issue.